# Возвращает результат победы в лотерее 10, 5, 1 или 0 в соответствии с входными значениями

Tags: python

```py
def lottery(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    if a == 5 and b == 5 and c == 5:
        return 10
    elif a != 5 and b != 5 and c != 5:
        return 5
    elif a != b and a != c:
        return 1
    elif a == b or a == c:
        return 0

print(lottery(5, 5, 5))  #10
print(lottery(2, 2, 1))  #0
print(lottery(2, 3, 1))  #1
print(lottery(0, 0, 3))  #0
print(lottery(5, 1, 5))  #0
```

В коде видимо необходимо сделать какие-то настройки алгоритма, чтобы он выдавал правильные ответы. На данный момент он выдает `10; 5; 5; 5; 0`.
Где допущена ошибка и как её изменить?

Условия:

1. Если все три числа являются «выигрышными», т. е. 5, то возвращается самый высокий выигрышный результат — 10.
2. Если все три числа просто одинаковы, но не равны «выигрышному числу», то возвращается средний выигрышный результат - 5.
3. Если и b, и c отличны от a, выигрышный результат равен 1.
   В противном случае, если либо b, либо c равно a, выигрышный результат равен 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не соблюдается второе условие равенства всех переменных и неравенства их `5`. Вот здесь

```py
elif a != 5 and b != 5 and c != 5: # возьмем a = 2, b = 2, c = 1
```

При указанных значениях в комментарии вы получите `True` на этом условии, а в задаче еще сказано, что все переменные должны быть равны между собой, то есть условие должно выглядеть так

```py
elif a == b == c != 5: # равны между собой и не равны 5
```

Полностью код для вашей задачи будет

```py
def lottery(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    if a == b == c == 5:
        return 10
    elif a == b == c != 5:
        return 5
    elif a != b and a != c:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Проверка

```py
>>> print(lottery(5, 5, 5))  #10
10
>>> print(lottery(2, 2, 1))  #0
0
>>> print(lottery(2, 3, 1))  #1
1
>>> print(lottery(0, 0, 3))  #0
0
>>> print(lottery(5, 1, 5))  #0
0
```